# Can not log in to our Microsoft Teams add in app

Tags: android, azure, authentication, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

We are currently deploying our app to Microsoft Teams. We are using Azure sigle sign on for log in to our app. Everything works fine for iOS, when you click on login a modal window pops up where you log in using your Microsoft account.

When it comes to Android, we can not log in into our app. The log in page loads but after clicking on Login, a modal windows pops up ( where there is supposed to be the Microsoft log in ) but it immediately closes, therefore we can not log into our app.

Does anyone know what might be the cause of this issue?

Comment: This Question does not belong on StackOverflow

Comment: Is there any console error you are getting? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools#access-devtools-from-an-android-device

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT we are getting an error, but we have trouble finding out what type of error it is.

Comment: @Matus - Can you please share the console logs, if any ? Also, please let us know that authentication mechanism that you have used (reference doc or code snippet) ?

Comment: @Matus - Can you please share the details or repro steps , so that we can investigate further on your issue?